# using js reduce method. just a matter of style?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, undefined, reduce

I'm using js and trying to decide on the style of my code.

I need to find the age of the youngest person inside a people collection. My question is: should i return undefined in case of empty array ? Should i let it fail in case of empty array?

This is what i did:

```js
let people = [{name: "a", age: 20}, {name: "b", age: 21}]

function nameOfYoungestPerson(people) {

    let yst = youngest(people)
    
    return yst && yst.name

}

function youngest(people) {

    return people.reduce((yst, person) => yst === undefined ? person : 
               (person.age < yst.age ? person : yst), undefined)
}
```

The other option would be letting it fail:

```js
function youngest(people) {
    return people.reduce((yst, person) => person.age < yst.age ? person : yst) 
}
```

**Also**, which one is better:

```js
function youngest(people) {

    return people.reduce((yst, person) => yst === undefined ? person : 
               (person.age < yst.age ? person : yst), undefined)
}
```

Or:

```js
function youngest(people) {

    return empty(people) ? undefined : people.reduce((yst, person) => 
                                              person.age < yst.age ? person : yst)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it fail. It's the caller's responsibility to ensure that the parameters be valid, and if they're not, it's best to let the caller know as soon as possible. If you return undefined, the caller will keep running and your program will fail much later once you actually try to do something with the undefined value. At that point you'll probably have a hard time figuring out where that undefined value came from.

Of course it would be nicer to write a function that cannot crash. However the problem is that if the array is empty, there isn't really any useful value that you can return. null and undefined will probably just defer the crash to a later point. Unless of course the caller checks for an undefined return value, but then what's the advantage over just having the caller check that the array is nonempty? There isn't any.

Of the two variants that you've shown, the second one is better, because each loop iteration will only evaluate one conditional. The first one will evaluate two conditionals per iteration, making it less efficient.

Comment: "Unless of course the caller checks for an undefined return value, but then what's the advantage over just having the caller check that the array is nonempty?" I'm coming from  java and Optional would have been my choice here. But i can't find something similiar in js. I think returning null (not undefined) would be the closest. Would it ?

Comment: Yes, in a statically typed language I'd go for something like `Optional` too. But the main advantage of that is that it uses the type system to ensure that the empty case is handled correctly. But there is no type system in JavaScript, so why bother? There's a million different mistakes that you can make when calling that function that will make it crash (eg. pass an array with something other than people), so I don't see why you would check for empty arrays in particular.

Comment: ok, let's say you need to find the minimum number in array. what would you return in case of empty array? null, undefined or throw Error?. same goes for finding de maximum , finding the first that satisfies a condition, etc. i'm struggling with corner cases like those in js,

Comment: I'd let it throw an error, for the reasons I already explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't "let it fail", but if you 100% know that the array will always have people in it, you *could* not build in a case for it.

Adding in a way to handle an empty array is pretty easy though so I would probably just do it. I suggest not returning undefined as that can cause confusion and instead return null, because if the name doesn't exist on an object it could also return undefined which would cause unexpected behavior.

For your question on how to style it, I would suggest handling the empty case on a separate line because the one-line solutions you have there are pretty long and difficult to quickly read imho.

```js
function youngest(people) {
    if (!people.length) return null;
    return people.reduce((yst, person) => person.age < yst.age ? person : yst) 
}
```